# SMW semantic mediawiki #ask code with images

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

On my wiki bi.maunishshah.com I am using a semantic mediawiki (SMW) to generate tables for each page. I am trying to add images to that table using the #ask query.

I can't seem to resize the images and remove border or anything to those images. Can someone plz help me out.

Comment: How does the code look that you tried using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming part of your query is to return a property like `|? Image`, then you should consider using `|format=template |template=<Results_row>` to make use of a template to format your results. In this example, Template:Results_row will control any formatting of the output. For example, `[[{{{Image|}}}|options|caption]]`, per the standard MediaWiki documentation. Of course you would include formatting of all the other properties returned from the query with this template.

Comment: we tried something else and it worked. have a look at http://bi.maunishshah.com/Double_Mohur